# Is it thread safe using static variable in the SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, multithreading

Is it thread safe ? To use static variable SQL statement to retrieve the data from a single table in the multi threaded environment. There is a possibility of
many instances accessing the SQL statement at the same time.

```
private static String SELECT_PP_INFO = " SELECT PP_ID,PP_NAME FROM TABLENAME WHERE PP_ID= ? AND PP_BRANCH= ? ";
```

Comment: Well are you ever going to change that variable? If not, make it final to make that obvious.

Comment: Make if `private static final String` and it is entirely safe.

Comment: This is not SQL statement, this is only string, and is safe. BUT: YES, using multiple queries has few muti thread risk, and query string is the smallest problem (or not is at all)

Comment: @CodeMatrix: If you change the string, it's still thread-safe.

Comment: Thank you all. But one question, If multiple instances call the at the same time.

for example: (first param PP_ID, second param PP_BRANCH)

    Instance1 -> 1, AN
    Instance2 -> 2, BN
    ....
    Instance100-> 100, AT.

we have 100 different objects, All the instances at the same time trying to access the SELECT_PP_INFO static variable. And only one copy of SELECT_PP_INFO available for all the objects. So, it is possible to get messed up result ?

Based on your answer I understood it wont happen but I wanted to know more about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend making it `final`, but other than that it should be fine.  Strings are immutable so they're inherently thread safe for concurrent reads.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object